# How to deal with a rapidly growing mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

I have two tables in mysql database

1. tbl_comments
2. tbl_votes

When a User Clicks on a Like or Dislike button under the comment, a new row is inserted in the tbl_votes, with comment_id, user_id and vote_type. It means if 100 users click the Like or Dislike button on 100 comments per day, it will insert 10,000 rows in tbl_votes table. So, with increasing number of users and increasing number of votes, tbl_votes will be increased rapidly. And suppose when there are 100,000,000 rows in tbl_votes then it will also effect the performance and slow down the sql queries.

How can I deal with this solution or any other solution.

Comment: Which engine do you have?

Comment: On a large table that no longer fits in RAM, the biggest detriment to the performance tends to be the I/O (i.e. the relative slowness of hard or even solid-state drives). So, design your database to minimize the I/O and you should be fine - take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15200906/533120) to you other question for some ideas.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly fine solution.
As long as you have the indexes set correct it's okay.(index on primary key, and post id)

Take forexample stackoverflow, every post, reply comment has it's own voting system, up or down, remembers who voted, and they have about 200million+ messages+replies with each their own votes, and still it responds quickly.

As long as the indexes are set correctly, it should perform just fine. I might suggest using a bigint for the primary key though...

Comment: I second that. If there's really any slowdown, it might be due to poor database design or other factors (memory, HDD speed).

Comment: I have a little confusion about your phrase "(index on primary key, and post id)". What is meant by index on primary key? Is Primary Key not an Index itself?

Comment: Yes, primary key is an index in itself, but you do have to set it. You'd be suprised how many people forget to set the "ID" column to a primary key. They set it as auto increment, but not as an primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about application performance with `1 billion` rows on a machine that can keep the indexes in memory.

Performance depends on:

1. How many joins those queries do
2. How well your indexes are set up
3. How much ***RAM*** is in the machine
4. Speed and number of processors
5. Type and spindle speed of hard drives
6. size of the row/amount of data returned in the query

Answer (score 0):

Some conclusions:

If you go for rdbms:
Doesn't really matter how many rows you insert into table if it's correctly indexed to select sum of total likes for a comment, of course you'l need to keep result cached.
Another way for fast data selection - is to keep some vote data aggregated, so if user votes up for a comment there would be 1 insert/delete in your table and update on another table like

```
comment_id
rate
```

So you'l select rate for any comment you need, and total rows of aggregated table would be much less.

Another good way is to use key-value storage. Suppose that your key would be comment_id, and stored value for raw data

```
user_id
vote_type
```

Depending or noSql storage you select, data may be totally stored in memory and all select/update operations will work really fast

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally true that the size of table does not affect the `SELECT` query.
For big tables, I would suggest TokuDB.

In both cases the problem will arise when you want to `DELETE` some data.
At that point, you have 2 choices: clustered keys or begin to think to different architectures (horizontal sharding could be a good way):